# Text file and Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a problem doing som changes to a `*.txt` file.
The data have this format:

```
11,2003,1,1,9,38,40.38,1
11,2003,1,1,9,47,2.5,1
11,2003,1,1,10,34,43.88,1
11,2003,1,1,10,38,14.5,1
11,2003,1,1,12,47,13.2,1
```

Where the columns are station number,year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds and precipitation(1 = 0.1 mm)

The times that have precipitation = 0 are not included in the list. This results in hours without rainfall will be absent. For these cases I want to make one entry for the first minute of the hour without rainfall in the New file, to show that there has been made measurements. Like this:

```
50810,200301010938,0.1 
50810,200301010947,0.1 
50810,200301011034,0.1 
50810,200301011038,0.1
50810,200301011100,0.0   <---- This is what I need to get in the New file
50810,200301011247,0.1
```

(New station number, date/time, precipitation)

For now I've come up With this:

```
clear all

data = load('jan-31des_2003.txt'); %opens file with data
fid=fopen('50810_2003','w'); %opens empty file to write
[nrow, ncol] = size(data); %size of data
fprintf(fid,'%5s %12s %5s \r\n','Snr','Dato - Tid','RR_01') %Header

for row = 1:nrow 

y = data(row,2); %year
m = data(row,3); % month
d = data(row,4); % date
h = data(row,5); % hour
M = data(row,6); % minute
p = data(row,8); % precipitation
p = p*0.1


end

fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if command to check if the next hour you are looking at is more than a single hour ahead from the last one. If that's the case you can create a new entry at this point:

```
if data(row,5) > (data(row-1,5)+1)
  y = data(row,2); %year
  m = data(row,3); % month
  d = data(row,4); % date
  h = data(row,5)+1; % hour
  M = 00; % minute
  p = 0; % precipitation
end
```

after this part you will need to make check again if there is another 'skipped' hour and so on. You should also replace your for-loop, by a while-loop until you reach the last entry in your dataset.

Try to implement this idea and come back to us with your code in case it didn't work out.